# Fastest way to create a new file with a specific number of zero's

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory tree that in each directory there is a file called zero-file
I want this file to be initialized with specific number of zero's for example 10000000000.
I want to write ASCII character '0'
I found 2 solutions for this

```
for i in `seq 1 10000000000`
do
    echo -n 0 >> zero-file
done
```

The second one is this: I initialized a file called base and the copy this file in each directory

```
cp base zero-file
```

This was faster. 
I want to know if there exist a faster way.

Comment: Did you want the file to be full of binary zeros or the ASCII character `'0'`?

Comment: @e0k ASCII charactor zero, thanks, I edited my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To write zeros to zero-file:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=10000000000 | tr '\0' '0' > zero-file
```

Comment: This version creates binary zeros, then translates them to the ASCII character `'0'`.  I thought you wanted _real_ binary zeros, not the character (which is really 48).  After the clarification that you want `'0'` (ASCII character) instead of `'\0'` (binary value zero), I think this is the version you'd want.

Comment: If the file length is a large multiple of e.g. 1000 or 1024, I would instead set `bs=1000` or `bs=1024` and divide `count` by the same number; that should be faster (because `dd` would use a buffer)

Comment: As noted by @BasileStarynkevitch it is often possible to increase the performance with a larger blocksize (bs). Example: `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1000000 count=10000 | tr '\0' '0' > zero-file`. Important: You need blocksize in bytes as available RAM.

Answer (score 10):

Try using `/dev/zero` as a virtual input file that contains only zeros.  You can copy a fixed number of bytes with `dd`:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=zero-file bs=1 count=10000000000
```

This copies one byte 10000000000 times from `/dev/zero` to `zero-file`.  You can adjust the blocksize and count as needed.

Answer (score 1):

according to @Cyrus answer:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=10000000000 | tr '\0' '0' > zero-file
```

you said that:

> I have a directory tree that in **each directory** there is a file called
>   zero-file

so you have to do this command several time
My idea is to save it in a file once and for the other directories use that file that contains those 0's.

```
#for the first time
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=10000000000 | tr '\0' '0' > zero-file
#for other directories
$ dd if=../zero-file of=zero-file bs=1 count=10000000000
```